# Como acessar as propriedades de um dado que está definido com tipo "object" em TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estou usando uma biblioteca [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken), que define o tipo do retorno de um *callback* como `object | undefined`. Eu preciso usar esse objeto pra acessar uma propriedade específica, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
verify('', '', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    // Handle Error
    throw new Error(err);
  } 

  // Generate the new acessToken
  doSomething(data?.property) // Property doesn't exists on type object
  doSomething(data) // data is probably undefined 
});
```

Eu não consegui descobrir como lidar com esse tipo de erro. Abaixo segue um trecho da definição de tipos da biblioteca em questão:

```
export type VerifyCallback = (
  err: VerifyErrors | null,
  decoded: object | undefined,
) => void;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a definição de tipos da biblioteca que você passou, o tipo do segundo parâmetro do *callback* é `object | undefined`.

Isso significa que, apesar do encadeamento opcional (`?.`) permitir que você "acesse" uma propriedade de um objeto que possivelmente é `undefined`, o tipo `object` (definido pela biblioteca) não diz que há uma propriedade `property`, que você está tentando acessar. Essa é a causa do erro.

Isso significa que você deve fornecer um tipo para se livrar do erro:

```
interface YourDecodedObject {
  property: string;
}

verify('foo', 'foo', (err, decoded: YourDecodedObject) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  console.log(decoded.property);
});
```

Uma outra opção seria usar [asserções de tipo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

Num mundo ideal, essa função `verify` aceitaria um [genérico](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) para dar um tipo ao segundo parâmetro do *callback*, mas de acordo com a definição que você passou, esse parece não ser o caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Eu ainda não tinha conhecimento das asserções de tipo, achei bastante útil pra esse caso.